# Return min value of key as a property of the collection

Tags: c#

I have defined a new class called Diversion inherited from Dictionary to hold a set of DateTime keys and associated int values.

I would like to return the earliest key value and average int value as properties of the class (assuming it has been populated).

Is there a more efficient way to iterate over the dictionary?  How do I reference the instance of the class when I'm defining it?

Thanks for all help in advance!

```
   public class Diversion : Dictionary<DateTime, int>
{
    private DateTime _starttime;
    private decimal _avg;

    public DateTime Starttime {
        get {
            if (Diversion.count > 0) {
                _starttime = new DateTime(2999,1,1);
                foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> de in Diversion) {
                    if (de.key < _starttime) _starttime = de.key;
                }
                return _starttime;
            }
            else    return; 
         }
    }

    public DateTime AvgVal {
        get {
            if (Diversion.count > 0) {
                _avg = 0;
                foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> de in Diversion) {
                    _avg = _avg + de.value;
                }
                _avg = _avg / Diversion.count;
                return _avg;
            }
            else    return; 
         }
    }       

    public Diversion() {}
}
```

Comment: `this` is your friend

Comment: why not keep track of these things as the dictionary is manipulated, rather than computing them when needed

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use LINQ to hide your complexity.
[Dictionary.Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Enumerable.Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354760(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Enumerable.Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354760(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public DateTime Starttime 
{
    get 
     {
        if (this.Count > 0) 
        {
             return this.Keys.Min();    
        }
        return new DateTime(2999,1,1);;
     }
}

public DateTime AvgVal 
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Count > 0) 
           return this.Values.Average();  
        else    
           return DateTime.MinValue; //something must be returned.
   }
}
```

When you extend any class (Dictionary in this case), you can access all the properties of base class (and current class), using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) keyword. In your code, you are using base class name, which is incorrect.

Comment: Your `AvgVal` property returns the wrong value, it should be the average of the values. Also note that the main problem with the OP's code is they are using `Diversion` instead of `this` so you might want to emphasise that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *inheriting* `Dictionary<TK,TV>`, you could *implement* `IDictionary<TK,TV>` wrapping an actual dictionary. This way you could control access to the wrapped dictionary, maintaining the current minimum and total:

```
public class Diversion : IDictionary<DateTime,int> {
    private decimal currentTotal;
    private SortedSet<DateTime> keys = new SortedSet<DateTime>();
    private Dictionary<DateTime,int> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime,int>();
    ...
    public decimal AvgVal {
        get {
            if (dict.Count == 0) throw InvalidOperationException();
            return currentTotal / dict.Count;
        }
    }
    public DateTime StartTime {
        get {
            if (dict.Count == 0) throw InvalidOperationException();
            return keys.Min;
        }
    }
}
```

You will implement all methods of `IDictionary<DateTime,int>` by forwarding the call to the wrapped `dict`, with three exceptions:

- Operations that add new entries will need to add the key to `keys` and increase `currentTotal` by `value`,
- Operations that remove entries by key will need to remove the key and decrease `currentTotal`, and
- Operations that replace entries at the specific key will need to subtract the old value from `currentTotal`, and add the new value to the result.

This will let your additional operations `AvgVal` and `StartTime` to complete instantaneously, regardless of the current size of the collection. The flip side is that the implementation will need to maintain a balanced tree of keys, so all mutating operations will become O(log<sub>2</sub>n).